# Message Tracking Log for multiple wildcards / domains to one csv

Tags: powershell, csv, microsoft-exchange

I need to create a script which pulls the messagetracking logs of two domains,
`@domain1.com` and `@domain2.com`, to display which users or external email-adresses reached one of the two domains by sendindg a message.
The report should be inserted in a csv (of both wildcards).

I was able to get the script working with one domain, using the below command.

```
Get-TransportServer | 
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start((get-date).AddDays(-1)) -End(get-date) | 
    where {$_.recipients -like "*domain1.com*"} | 
    select sender, {$_.Recipients}, timestamp | 
    export-csv -delimiter "," -path C:\andcombined.csv -notype
```

Now I need to include a second domain to this... 
I barely **tried to add the second domain** but it doesn't work, see below.

```
Get-TransportServer | 
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start((get-date).AddDays(-1)) -End(get-date) | 
    where {$_.recipients -like "*domain1.com*" -and $_.recipients -like "*domain2.com*" | 
    select sender, {$_.Recipients}, timestamp | 
    export-csv -delimiter "," -path C:\andcombined.csv -notype
```

I would appreciate any help on this topic very much. 
Thank you all in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Please ignore the typos  **"$.recipients >>> "$._recipients"**  somehow it didnt copy paste correctly.

Comment: Try changing `-and $_.recipients -like "domain2.com"` to `-or $_.recipients -like "domain2.com"`.

Comment: I already tried that but ther's just one domain listed and the other is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`-and` would match items that are in BOTH domains. I can only assume this would be zero.

Change your where clause to this:

```
where {$_.recipients -like "*domain1.com*" -or $_.recipients -like "*domain2.com*"}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob Colvin, Thanks for your feedback. I already tried that and this results in a report where only one recipient domain is listed..

Comment: Are you confident your Get-MessageTrackingLog cmdlet is returning those results?